# Why doesn't the `explicit` keyword prevent a `char` from being converted into an `int`?

Tags: c++, constructor, implicit-conversion, c-strings, explicit

From what I understand, in the following code, `explicit A(int a)` should prevent `A b('g');` to use the **int** constructor:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:
        int x;
        char *y;

        A() : x(0) {}
        explicit A(int a) : x(a) { std::cout<<"INT\n"; }
        A(char *b) : y(b) { std::cout<<"C STRING\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    A a(5); /// output: "INT"
    A b('g'); /// output: "INT"
    A c("Hello"); /// output: "C STRING"
}
```

However, `A b('g');` uses the **int** constructor... Why?

Also, another question: If I write `A(const char *b)` instead of `A(char *b)`, it gives me the following error: **invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]**. Why can't I convert a `const char*` to `char*`?

Comment: Because that's what the standard requires. Given `A b('g')` the compiler looks for a constructor call that involves no more than a single implicit conversion of the `char` (i.e. `'g'`). It finds no constructor that accepts a `char` (by either value or `const` reference) but does find the constructor that accepts an `int`. A single implicit conversion can be used to convert from `char` to `int`, so the compiler converts `'g'` to `int`, and then calls the constructor that accepts an `int`.

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't the **explicit** keyword avoid that by not allowing **any** implicit conversions?

Comment: @H-005 No, it only affects the user-defined conversion function which is marked as `explicit`, like `A::A(int)` in your code. It won't affect standard conversion like `char` to `int`.

Comment: The `explicit` keyword means that `A x = 2` or `A y = 'g'` will fail, but `A x(2)` and `A y('g')` will not.   It has nothing to do with implicit conversions (like converting `'g'` from `char` to `int`) affecting the choice of which constructor will be invoked.

Answer (score 3):

You're using [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), which does consider `explicit` constructors.

> Direct-initialization is more permissive than copy-initialization: copy-initialization only considers non-[explicit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) constructors and non-explicit user-defined [conversion functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator), while direct-initialization considers all constructors and all user-defined conversion functions.

Given `A b('g');`, `'g'` is an `char` and could convert to `int` implicitly, then `A::A(int)` is called to initialize the object.

On the other hand, [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) like `A a = 5;` and `A b = 'g';` won't work.

> In addition, the implicit conversion in copy-initialization must produce T directly from the initializer, while, e.g. direct-initialization expects an implicit conversion from the initializer to an argument of T's constructor.

And about

> Why can't I convert a `const char*` to `char*`?

`const char*` can't convert to `char*` implicitly. You can use `const_cast`, but note that it's dangerous, e.g. attempting to modify a string literal results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

The `explicit` keyword prevents implicit conversion from `int` to `A`. However, it doesn't affect the possibility of `char` to `int` conversion when calling `A` constructor directly.

In other words, `explicit` only affects conversion to your class `A` but it doesn't affect any possible conversions of constructor parameters.